# How to display AGE using trigger in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have two different tables in which I have created Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE  "STUD_PERS" 
   (    "ENROLL" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "BRANCH" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "YEAR" NUMBER, 
    "DATE0FBIRTH" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "STUD_PERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ENROLL") ENABLE
   )
```

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcqr7.jpg)

### Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE  "SCHO" 
   (    "ENROLL" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ANN_INC" NUMBER, 
    "AGE" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "SCHO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ENROLL") ENABLE
   )
```

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Drw1.jpg)

I want to write a Trigger to display AGE in Table 2 by using DATEOFBIRTH from Table 1

Comment: Trigger (http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/but-why.gif)? You want to update Table 2, whenever Table 1 gets new data inserted or what exactly? Can  a View "Fix" the issue that you have ?

Comment: You don't want to do this. You may think you do but you don't. AGE is derivable DATE_OF_BIRTH, and there's no benefit to storing it in a denormalized column. Especially as AGE will change over the lifetime of the record - once a year.

Comment: Yes I need to update/display table 2 AGE whenever table one DATEOFBIRTH is updated

Comment: Also, don'tr spray your question with random database tags. Different products do things differently. This is especially true with date-wrangling. Please choose the database flavour you're using.

Comment: @aadhil You don't need a trigger, you need a [Virtual Column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1).

Comment: You can't use a virtual column here. virtual columns don't allow to get columns from other tables.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso Good point. Which begs the question that does the age column belong with the students table, rather than the school table - unless perhaps that column is storing the age at enrolment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As I understood your question and comments there you need a trigger whenever UPDATE is happening, right? So if someone UPDATE the table1 then the TRIGGER have to UPDATE age on the table2, if it is then try this code:

```
---- TRIGGER will UPDATE the data of the column AGE in table2 whenever DATE0FBIRTH column has been UPDATED and COMMITTED:

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scho_age 
    AFTER UPDATE OF DATE0FBIRTH 
          ON  STUD_PERS
          REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
          FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
          UPDATE SCHO SET AGE = (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM :NEW.DATE0FBIRTH)) WHERE ENROLL= :OLD.ENROLL;
    END;
```

2) OR if you need to just Display then create a VIEW for table1 and query the AGE from there without duplicating the data:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT (YEAR from DATE0FBIRTH)) AGE from table1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much !